# How to add horizontal line after references (biblatex) and glossary title?

Tags: biblatex, formatting, glossaries, rules

I need to have horizontal lines after each title.

For `table of contents` this works with:

```
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\vskip 3em \auftaktvz}
```

and

```
\newcommand{\auftaktvz}{{\vspace{-24pt}\rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt}\vspace{-30pt}}{\noindent}}
```

So it looks like:

```
Table of contents
----------------------------------------

1. ABC
2. EDF ...
```

For chapters this works with:

```
\chapter{My chapter title}\auftakt
```

and

```
\newcommand{\auftakt}{{\vspace{-24pt}\rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt}\vspace{40.5pt}}{\noindent}}
```

so it looks like

```
My chapter title
-------------------------------------------

My text goes here...
```

How can I change the formatting of the references and glossaries titles so that a horizontal line is also drawn there?

```
\usepackage[bibstyle=authoryear, autocite=footnote, citestyle=authoryear-icomp, autopunct=false, urldate=long, abbreviate=false, dateabbrev=false, backend=biber]{biblatex}
[...]
\usepackage[toc,xindy,nonumberlist,numberedsection=autolabel]{glossaries}

[...]

\printbibliography
[...]
\printglossary[title=\glossaryname,toctitle=\glossaryname]
```

Currently these title heading are just printing like:

```
References

o Here comes list of authors...
```

and

```
Glossaries

List of Glossaries
```

How can I also get a horizontal line (rule) below the `References` and `Glossaries` titles?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to make a global reshaping of titles with `titlesec`?

Comment: @egreg: I got the style specifications from the book publisher, who also sent me those latex definition for `\auftakt` and `\auftaktvz`. So I'd rather not reshape everything globally. It works ok except for these two minor issues with the references and glossaries titles... Is it so hard to change just these two?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the documentation of the package `titlesec` you find how the normal chapter heading style can be defined and it's very easy to add a rule.

Adding `\auftakt` after all chapters is wrong, because it's error prone. If you want to modify the aspect of *all* chapter headings, you just need to act in *one* place. And this works for every chapter, even those added by `\tableofcontents`, `\printbibliography` or `\printglossary`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{xampl.bib}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
  {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}
  {20pt}
  {\Huge}
  [\vspace{1ex}\titlerule]
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{40pt}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{My chapter title}

\section{A section title}

Here's a citation \cite{article-full}.
\lipsum

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

### Table of contents page

[image]

### Chapter page

[image]

### Bibliography

[image]